# Where are the unsaved custom wallpapers saved?

Tags: desktop-background

I'm new here and I need an answer to a specific question to which I did not find any useful answer despite the fact that several other people here had asked some more-or-less similar questions.

Well, here is the fact: today I have found a nice wallpaper on the internet and I have installed it not by downloading, like usual, but by choosing the "lazy" way - just by clicking on  "set as desktop background". Soon after that, I have found another one and I did the same, not being pleased with the second one, I have decided to return to the first one.

And this is how I have discovered that I don't know where to take that lost wallpaper from! I the wallpaper folder it is not, in the photos folder, obviously, it is not, but I imagine that there must be a place somewhere, where the it is kept saved but I don't know where to look and how to reach it.

So, please, help me solve this. I repeat, I am a newbie, I need ABC-style explications.

I have tried to look for the file in Home folder, but I could not find it, be it invisible or not.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can't do anything about it. My best suggestion is to take any screenshots with the wallpaper and image search it on google and you might find the page. Just download it next time. Oh, also check the history of the browser. I'll update for more solutions.

Comment: Nebraska - Thank you! I did the History trick and I have found the wallpaper. But it is too bad that there is no other way to find it. It seems illogical somehow. I mean, it should be somewhere on the hard drive. Many years ago, I had a quite similar problem with Windows but it seem much easier to solve. I don't remember exactly the case and the solution - the distance in time and the difference between the two OS is too much to be of any help.

Comment: I agree, an operating system should save your wallpapers, maybe according to some settings.

Answer (score 1):

Your wallpaper is indeed saved on your computer:

```
cd ~/.cache/wallpaper
ls
```

or open your home folder in nautilus *view->show hidden files*
open folder *.cache*, open folder *wallpaper*

And get your wallpaper

Comment: thom - The command line gave no useful result. I have tried the Nautilus solution but in the folder Wallpaper there is only the actual wallpaper saved. There is none of the previous used wallpapers as I should aspect. So, I am still waiting for the solution. Anyway, thanks for trying to hep me!